# Another troubling system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've been working on solving some linear equations arising from different optimization problems, but I keep getting stuck. Right now I have the problem below:

I am trying to solve the system of equations for $x$:

$$ Ax-\alpha \frac{Bx}{ x^tBx}=c$$
$$e^tx=1$$
where $e=(1,...,1)^t$.

where $x,c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, both $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive definite and indeed even
$$A-\frac{\alpha B }{x^t B x}$$
is positive definite, so we have nice invertibility properties.

Any help, references, or much better - a solution - is very much appreciated!

EDIT: Some further work below.

If we set $x=\sqrt{B}^{-1}z$ we get
$$A\sqrt{B}^{-1}z-\alpha\frac{\sqrt{B}z}{z^tz}-c=0$$
or for $D=\sqrt{B}^{-1}A\sqrt{B}^{-1}/\alpha$ and $p=\sqrt{B}^{-1}c/\alpha$
$$0=Dz-\frac{z}{z^tz}-p\Leftrightarrow (D-\frac{pz^t}{z^tz})z=\frac{z}{z^tz}.$$
So it appears that $z$ is a multiple of an eigenvalue of a matrix that in turn depends on $z$. Is there any way I can extract analyical solutions!?

Comment: So, I was having a think, in the case of $c=0$ (which isn't really that interesting but gotta start somewhere) we can transform the system into
$Dz=\frac{z}{z^tz}$, so $z$ is a multiple of an eigenvector. Can we then somehow use linearity to extract a solution for $c\neq 0$?

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $x^T$ on the left, then you get:
$$x^TAx - \alpha = x^T c \iff x^T(Ax - c) = \alpha.$$Maybe that could help. I can't say it's equivalent to the original equation, but it reduces the possible solutions.

Comment: You can decompose $x = e+\delta$ where $\delta\cdot e = 0$. This might open up some new avenues.

Comment: I spent some time trying those approaches. Thanks for the tip, but I am afraid I cannot see it leading anywhere. 

While browsing my library on linear algebra I encountered some sections on Hankel and Bezout forms. I only glanced quickly at it before having to leave for a lunch, but thought that it looked useful. Does anyone who has experience in the area have any suggestions as to its applicability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we decompose the vector $x$ as a component along and orthogonal to $e$, (i.e., $x=e+\Delta:\Delta \cdot e = 0$) and then apply this to the simplified form provided by @TheoBendit, we get:

$$(e+\Delta)^t(A(e+\Delta)-c)=\alpha \implies$$
$$e^tAe+\Delta^tAe+e^tA\Delta+\Delta^tA\Delta-e^tc-\Delta^tc = \alpha \implies $$
$$ \langle\Delta,\mathbf{a}_{\cdot j}\rangle+ \langle\Delta,\mathbf{a}_{i\cdot}\rangle +\mathbf{Q}_{A}(\Delta)-\langle c,\Delta\rangle=\alpha-\sum a_{ij}+\sum c_i \equiv K$$

So, we've (reduced?!) this to a quadratic equation in $n$ variables. If we let $\delta_i$ be the $i$th component of $\Delta$ then:

$$ \left(2\sum a_{ij}-\sum c_i\right) \sum \delta_i+\sum\sum a_{ij}\delta_i\delta_j-K=0 $$

Subject to:

$$\sum \delta_i = 0$$

Let $\mathbf{v}:=(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ be a solution to this formula, then your $x$ is $x=v+e$. There will likely be several solutions to this formula, but since its a quadratic form, you can apply any number of multivariate root finding algorithms to solve it. Or you can search the trove of answer on MSE. Here
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/solving-quadratic-vector-equation).

Also, the general problem of solving underdefined quadratic systems (like that here), has been studied. See this [paper](http://www.goubin.fr/papers/CG02.pdf) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/596.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'm not 100% sure this question is settled yet but I am more and more accepting the possibility of having to go numerical/use computer. Anyway, I have one question in regard to solving the underdetermined system: How do we know that a solution to the undertermined system is a solution to the original system? To me it seems a bit like throwing out n-1 constraints, closing your eyes and praying. I mean, I see that any solution to the original system satisfies the simplified one, but not necessarily vice versa? Or am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: @ZMI I defined the solutions $\delta_i$ to be part of a vector that is orthogonal to $e$. Therefore, this solution is not relevant to the constraint on the inner product with $e$ and we have a new, unconstrained problem on a quadratic manifold within $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @ZMI so, lets say that $v$ is a solution to the simplified problem, then by adding $e$ to it, we ensure it not only satisfies your matrix equation, but also that its dot product with $e$ is 1. This will be true for any set of $\delta_i$ that are roots of the quadratic form.

Comment: @ZMI the simplified form $x^T(Ax-c) = \alpha$ does not care how we decompose $x$ as long as we do it consistently. This is due to the properties of vector spaces.

Comment: I see one problem, but I guess this is minor: Are we using the same $e$? Because as far I can see $e^tx=e^t(e+\Delta)=e^t e + e^t \Delta = e^t e =1+...+1=n \neq 1$. Maybe you wanted to decompose $x=\Delta +e/n$? I guess this should then give your result slightly altered.

Comment: @ZMI you are correct. For some reason, Is tarted treating $e$ like a unit vector!

Comment: Hm, okay, I did not realize that an $x$ solving $x^t f(x)=0$ also solves $f(x)=0$ I'll have to brush up on linear algebra I guess. (With $f(x)$ appropriate for the problem above)

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine what reason that is. The notation is a bit weird but I started running out of good symbols!

Comment: @ZMI I think the analogy here is $y^tf(y)=0 \implies x^tf(x)=\alpha$. All I did was re-express the problem using vectors within the hyperplane defined by $c\cdot \Delta =0$