# Norm minimization subject to quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I want to solve the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:approx_quad_2}
\min_{{\bf x}} \| {\bf x}\|_2^2 \quad \mbox{s.t.} \quad \\ \quad {\bf x}^\top {\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf x}^\top {\bf b} = c,
\end{equation}
where ${\bf Q}$ is a matrix and ${\bf b}$ is a vector and $c$ is a scalar.

We can solve this equation using the method of Lagrange multipliers.
\begin{align*}
& L({\bf x}, \lambda) = \| {\bf x} \|_2^2 - \lambda({\bf x}^\top {\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf x}^\top {\bf b} - c) \\
\implies &\nabla_{\bf x} L =  2 {\bf x} - 2 \lambda ({\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf b}) = 0 \\
& \nabla_\lambda L = {\bf x}^\top {\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf x}^\top {\bf b} - c = 0
\end{align*}

Taking the inner product of the first constraint with ${\bf x}$,
\begin{align*}
0 &= \| {\bf x} \|^2 - \lambda ({\bf x}^\top {\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf b}^\top {\bf x}) \\
&= \| {\bf x} \|^2 - \lambda c \\
\implies & \lambda = \frac{\| {\bf x} \|^2}{c}
\end{align*}

Plugin this in the first constraint,
\begin{align*}
0 &= {\bf x} - \lambda ({\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf b}) \\
&= {\bf x} - \frac{\| {\bf x} \|^2}{c} ({\bf Q} {\bf x} + {\bf b}) \\
\implies & \frac{{\bf x}}{\| {\bf x} \|^2} - \frac{1}{c} {\bf Q} {\bf x} = \frac{{\bf b}}{c} \\
\implies & {\bf x} = \left( \frac{{\bf I}}{\| {\bf x} \|^2} - \frac{1}{c} {\bf Q} \right)^{-1} \frac{{\bf b}}{c}
\end{align*}

This gives us a transcendental equation, there might not be a closed-form solution.

Alternatively, I tried to complete the square to solve the second constraint (see e.g. [Solving quadratic vector equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52730/solving-quadratic-vector-equation)) but I also got to a transcendental equation. Is there another technique to solve this problem?

Comment: Any known properties on $Q$?

Comment: ${\bf Q}$ could be symmetric.

Comment: Yes, that can always be assumed without loss of generality, more interesting about definiteness or semidefiniteness

Comment: Ok, ${\bf Q}$ is not necessarily PSD in my problem, although I'm happy if we can already solve the PSD case. Does the PSD property help to solve this problem?

Comment: With a positive definite $Q$ you should be able to make a variable change and write the problem as the classical trust-region problem. That is probably both good and bad news. Good in the sense that it puts it in a classical framework, bad in the sense that the trust-region problem does not have a closed form solution, but essentially arrives at what you have, and then performs a numerical search.

Comment: I see, this is an interesting observation. Also bad news since I was hoping for a closed-form formula.